# Django Oscar automatically empties the basket on redeeming an expired voucher

Tags: django, django-oscar

When a customer applies a voucher to an item in the cart and the voucher expires during the checkout process or inside the cart itself. During the checkout process, when clicked on `place order`, the cart automatically empties and the customer is sent this error, `You need to add some items to your basket to checkout`, this happens during the `check_basket_is_not_empty method`.

Can someone help me understand which part of Django-Oscar could be modifying the cart in such drastic way. My initial thought was, that the cart was getting emptied because some oscar component was trying to remove the voucher and was removing the cart item as well. But during some more checks I find out that the voucher is successfully removed but the cart item only gets removed inside the `PaymentDetailsView`, probably.

I don't have the code to PaymentDetailsView. I started the job as a Django developer a couple of days ago and I was thrown into this huge django-oscar code base, which I am completely unfamiliar with. I am not allowed to post any code online. I don't know what to do, and don't want to get fired. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related - https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/3040 (I know that's you, but it's good to have the link here, for future users)

Comment: I just yesterday figured out what was going on, I will post my answer here and on Github as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what's causing this bug, but I came up with this solution. When you click "place order", the `PaymentDetailsView` class gets triggered, and the first function to deal with all the data is the `submit` one. So inside that, you can manually check the vouchers you have in the `request` and remove the vouchers manually.

```
# removing expired vouchers:
for voucher in self.request.basket.vouchers.all():
     if voucher.is_expired() or not voucher.is_available_to_user(user=self.request.basket.owner)[0]:
        self.request.basket.vouchers.remove(voucher)
        messages.error(self.request,_("The '%(code)s' voucher has expired") % {'code': voucher.code})
```